# perl regex variable with slashes

Tags: regex, perl

I need a perl regex to check if $currentSearch is present in $currentLine. 
The check should include that $currentLine has "Load" keyword in it.

match

```
$currentSearch = DNA/3/44.com/index.html
```

TO

```
$currentLine = Load DNA/3/44.com/index.html .....(3)
```

I tried this but it's not matching...

```
if($currentLine[$k] =~ m/Load\s+$currentSearch[$i]\s+\.+\\(d+\)/)
```

**EDIT**
even this does not work

```
 if($currentLine[$k] =~ m/$currentSearch[$i]/)
```

Comment: If you are defining the currentSearch and currentLine vars as you have posted you need to get rid of the array brackets since it is not an array of strings (and $k as well), as in my answer.  If you are actually defining currentSearch and currentLine as arrays please post the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that your problems come from not using:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

in your script.

First off, the strings in your first two statements, `$currentSearch` and `$currentLine`, has no quotes around them. That's probably a typo, but it looks odd.

Second, in your if statement, you refer to them as arrays instead of scalars. Supposing this is not another typo, that might be the source of your problem. `$currentSearch` and `$currentSearch[$i]` is referring to two completely different variables.

Without warnings and strict, even using two undeclared and undefined variables will not cause any sign of something being wrong.

In fact this:

```
perl -e 'if ($foo[0]=~ /$bar[1]/) { print "sure, why not?" }'
```

Will actually be a successful match, and will print the string, even though both variables `@foo` and `@bar` are completely empty. With `strict` and `warnings`, it will crash and burn like it should.

Anyway, this works:

```
my $cs = "DNA/3/44.com/index.html";
my $cl = "Load DNA/3/44.com/index.html .....(3)";

if ( $cl =~ /Load\s+$cs[\s\.]+\((\d+)\)/ ) {
    print "Yes: $1\n";
} else { print "Nope!" }
```

If you have any meta characters in the search string, it can cause hard to detect errors, in which case you can try to throw in a `quotemeta` on your search string.

Answer (score 3):

You have an error - you need to escape the d character to catch digits instead of the 'd' char.  Also you have one too many backslashes (you miss the first paren).

Here's a script that works:

```
$currentSearch = "DNA/3/44.com/index.html";


$currentLine = "Load DNA/3/44.com/index.html .....(3)";


if($currentLine =~ /Load\s+$currentSearch\s+\.+\(\d+\)/) {
    print "matched\n";
} else {
    print "no match\n";
}
```

Comment: There is no requirement to match the ".....(3)". Just stop with `$currentSearch`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($currentLine =~ /Load\s+\Q$currentSearch\E/) { ... }
```